# Java Comparator, comparing two doubles:

Tags: java, oop, lambda, comparator, java-17

I use Java 17. Here is my code:

```
    public static class SortByPercentLike implements VideoSorterInterface {
        // define Lambda Function
        Comparator<Video> videoPercentLikeComparator = (a,b) -> {
            Double firstVideoPercentLike =  ((a.getLike() - a.getDislike())/ (double) a.getView());
            Double secondVideoPercentLike = ((b.getLike() - b.getDislike())/ (double) b.getView());
            return firstVideoPercentLike.compareTo(secondVideoPercentLike);
        };

        @Override
        public void sort(List<Video> videos) {
            videos.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(videoPercentLikeComparator));
        }
    }
```

Comparator.comparingDouble(videoPercentLikeComparator) part gives me the error:

```
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Comparator<Video> conforms to ToDoubleFunction<? super T>
```

What is the problem

I have no idead what the error message means.

Comment: Can't you do `videos.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> ((a.getLike() - a.getDislike())/ (double) a.getView()))`?

Comment: `comparingDouble` needs a `ToDoubleFunction`, that is, a function that returns a `double` - it does not take (nor need) a **second** Comparator - Just use `videos.sort(videoPercentLikeComparator)`

Comment: If you want to use `comparingDouble`, don’t implement a `Comparator` manually. Use, e.g. `Comparator<Video> videoPercentLikeComparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(v -> (v.getLike() - v.getDislike())/ (double)v.getView());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, `videos.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(videoPercentLikeComparator));` should just be `videos.sort(videoPercentLikeComparator);`